# Android：how to change attributes in ondraw() by onclickListener

Tags: android

I have a simple ondraw() function.

```
private class MyViewCircle extends View {
        public MyViewCircle(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(20, 20, 50,
                    paint);
        }
    }
```

It works good. But I want it more interesting. I create a onclickListener.
evolve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //How to change attributes?
        }
    });
```

When I click the button, the attributes will be changed. For example, change to

```
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawCircle(30, 30, 50,paint);
```

My question is: How could I implement this? When I click the button, the image will be automatically re-generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could set some variables to represent there attributes, for example, in your case,you can set a n int for the color, and three float for the coordinates of the center and the radius.

in your onClick() method, change the values of there variables , and then call invalidate() to redraw the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a member variable to store the state, change it `onClick`, and check it in `onDraw`.

To hook up the click event properly, make sure you call `setOnClickListener` in your constructor, and call `invalidate` in `onClick` to force a redraw.

```
private class MyCircle extends View implements OnClickListener {
  private boolean mDrawBlueCircle = false;
  private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

  public MyCircle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float x = 20;
    float y = 20;
    float r = 50;
    int color = Color.BLACK;
    if (mDrawBlueCircle) {
      x = 30;
      y = 30;
      color = Color.BLUE;
    }
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    mDrawBlueCircle = true;
    invalidate();
  }
}
```

Notice that I also store the `Paint` in a member variable `mPaint`. This prevents new objects to be created on each draw cycle and reduces garbage collection.