# How to create a Button to show histograms? (Histogram sample code provided)

Tags: android, xml, graph, bitmap, histogram

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now and would really appreciate some help. I am a beginner in Android dev and I was developing an Android application which would show the histograms of the RGB values of `bitmaps1[0]`.

I found some code that draws the histogram [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/) but I am not sure how to make it show the histogram of `bitmaps1[0]` once the user clicks on a `ShowRGB` Button

I want the graphs to be displayed on top of `ImageView` once the user clicks the button `ShowRGB` and when the user clicks the button again the graphs disappear.

I have also attached a mockup of the layout and the graphs that I wish to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090435/how-to-plot-histogram-using-rgb-pixel-value

Comment: @RossC hi mate, that's strictly for Java and I cant use that for Android implementation even though Android is based on Java.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740059/how-to-generate-image-histogram-in-android

Comment: @RossC Thanks for that, will try it tomorow and see if I can get it working

Comment: Misinterpreted. I'll delete the answer. Not concerned about bounty, just want the thing to work for you!! You can use the button click listener to tell it to run the histogram, if it's already done get it to destroy the histogram. You could load it in a new activity and swap between the image and the histogram. I don't have the SDK here in work, but once I'm home I'll have a go. The code in the link is a good start to get the histogram drawing. Then we can look at activities / buttons / whatever else. Do it in stages.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Or, is the issue solved? From the comments, it looks like you're waiting for RossC to post an answer.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: Sorry been violently sick over the weekend. This link I gave should answer everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740059/how-to-generate-image-histogram-in-android  I can't write the entire thing from scratch and I have no ADK in this office, so can't test. Have you got the histogram drawing yet? Remember to break the functionality up. Draw the histogram. The Android UI part comes at the end (buttons etc) once the basics are working.

Comment: @RossC The histogram code (in the updated question) works however I am not sure how to write the `onClick` method of a button that will allow the display of histograms.

Comment: Ok so have a think about this. When you click your button the onClick method is called. You need a boolean to see if you have already clicked it or not (that will DRAW or UNdraw the histogram). You have a method to draw a histogram.... You're so close to this. Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408922/androidhow-to-change-attributes-in-ondraw-by-onclicklistener and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628617/execute-the-code-inside-ondraw-only-after-the-click-in-view    I can't just cobble it all together and you will learn a lot getting this to work.

Comment: @User1204501 please do feel free to step in. I'm in work and my ability to use S.O. is severely limited / frowned upon! I'm having to rush this a lot. All help appreciated! :)

Comment: @RossC I am messing around with the solution from the link you posted as we speak! will let you know how I go =D

Comment: @rossC the solution provided in the link is quite confusing as I am not sure where he has added the code or what he has removed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a layout with visibility `View.Gone` on your layout `activity_edit_pictures` in the place that you would want your custom view to appear. And then, when your button is pressed just do this:

Your code with some changes (DrawOnTop inside the activity):

```
public class testrgb extends Activity {
    /************************
     * PROPERTIES
     **********************/
    /* Tag for Log */
    public static final String TAG = "PiccaFinal.EditPicturesActivity";
    /* Images Path */
    private String[] _imagesPath;
    /* Original Images */
    private Bitmap[] _originalBitmaps = new Bitmap[2];
    /* Final Filtered Images */
    private Bitmap[] _filteredBitmaps = new Bitmap[2];

    /* Image View */
    private ImageView _filterImageView;

    private Preview mPreview;
    private DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;
    private Boolean is_showing= false;
    private Bitmap bitmap_todecode=null;




    int[] pixels;

    /************************
     * ANDROID METHODS
     **********************/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_pictures);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _imagesPath = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MainActivity.IMAGES_PATH);

        for (int i = MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE; i <= MainActivity.RIGHT_IMAGE; i++) {
            _originalBitmaps[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagesPath[i]);
        }

        _filterImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.filter_image_view);
        _filterImageView
                .setImageBitmap(_originalBitmaps[MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE]);
setBitmap_todecode(_originalBitmaps[MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE]);
        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // display_RGB
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layout_you_created);

        Button display_RGBButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display_RGB);
        display_RGBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(is_showing){ //if is already showing you hide the layout
                    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }  else {         //else you draw it with your custom view - the view should be in your class 
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll.addView(new DrawOnTop(this.getApplicationContext()));
                }



            });

        }


    }

    /**
     * @return the bitmap_todecode
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmap_todecode() {
        return bitmap_todecode;
    }

    /**
     * @param bitmap_todecode the bitmap_todecode to set
     */
    public void setBitmap_todecode(Bitmap bitmap_todecode) {
        this.bitmap_todecode = bitmap_todecode;
    }

    class DrawOnTop extends View {
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        Paint mPaintBlack;
        Paint mPaintYellow;
        Paint mPaintRed;
        Paint mPaintGreen;
        Paint mPaintBlue;
        byte[] mYUVData;
        int[] mRGBData;
        int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
        int[] mRedHistogram;
        int[] mGreenHistogram;
        int[] mBlueHistogram;
        double[] mBinSquared;

        public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
            super(context);

            mPaintBlack = new Paint();
            mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mPaintBlack.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintYellow = new Paint();
            mPaintYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mPaintYellow.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintRed = new Paint();
            mPaintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintRed.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaintRed.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintGreen = new Paint();
            mPaintGreen.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mPaintGreen.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintBlue = new Paint();
            mPaintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaintBlue.setTextSize(25);

            mBitmap = null;
            mYUVData = null;
            mRGBData = null;
            mRedHistogram = new int[256];
            mGreenHistogram = new int[256];
            mBlueHistogram = new int[256];
            mBinSquared = new double[256];
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                mBinSquared[bin] = ((double)bin) * bin;
            } // bin
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            mBitmap= getBitmap_todecode();
            if (mBitmap != null)
            {
                int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
                int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
                int newImageWidth = canvasWidth;
                int newImageHeight = canvasHeight;
                int marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

                // Convert from YUV to RGB
                decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

                // Draw bitmap
                mBitmap.setPixels(mRGBData, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
                Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
                Rect dst = new Rect(marginWidth, 0, 
                        canvasWidth-marginWidth, canvasHeight);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, mPaintBlack);

                // Draw black borders                       
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0, marginWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawRect(canvasWidth - marginWidth, 0, 
                        canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);

                // Calculate histogram
                calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 0);
                calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mGreenHistogram, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 1);
                calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mBlueHistogram, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 2);

                // Calculate mean
                double imageRedMean = 0, imageGreenMean = 0, imageBlueMean = 0;
                double redHistogramSum = 0, greenHistogramSum = 0, blueHistogramSum = 0;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
                {
                    imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
                    redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
                    imageGreenMean += mGreenHistogram[bin] * bin;
                    greenHistogramSum += mGreenHistogram[bin];
                    imageBlueMean += mBlueHistogram[bin] * bin;
                    blueHistogramSum += mBlueHistogram[bin];
                } // bin
                imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
                imageGreenMean /= greenHistogramSum;
                imageBlueMean /= blueHistogramSum;

                // Calculate second moment
                double imageRed2ndMoment = 0, imageGreen2ndMoment = 0, imageBlue2ndMoment = 0;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
                {
                    imageRed2ndMoment += mRedHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                    imageGreen2ndMoment += mGreenHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                    imageBlue2ndMoment += mBlueHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                } // bin
                imageRed2ndMoment /= redHistogramSum;
                imageGreen2ndMoment /= greenHistogramSum;
                imageBlue2ndMoment /= blueHistogramSum;
                double imageRedStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageRed2ndMoment - imageRedMean*imageRedMean );
                double imageGreenStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageGreen2ndMoment - imageGreenMean*imageGreenMean );
                double imageBlueStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageBlue2ndMoment - imageBlueMean*imageBlueMean );

                // Draw mean
                String imageMeanStr = "Mean (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueMean);
                canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10, 30, mPaintYellow);

                // Draw standard deviation
                String imageStdDevStr = "Std Dev (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueStdDev);
                canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10, 60, mPaintYellow);

                // Draw red intensity histogram
                float barMaxHeight = 3000;
                float barWidth = ((float)newImageWidth) / 256;
                float barMarginHeight = 2;
                RectF barRect = new RectF();
                barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 200;
                barRect.left = marginWidth;
                barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
                {
                    float prob = (float)mRedHistogram[bin] / (float)redHistogramSum;
                    barRect.top = barRect.bottom - 
                        Math.min(80,prob*barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                    barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintRed);
                    barRect.left += barWidth;
                    barRect.right += barWidth;
                } // bin

                // Draw green intensity histogram
                barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 100;
                barRect.left = marginWidth;
                barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
                {
                    barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mGreenHistogram[bin])/((float)greenHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                    barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGreen);
                    barRect.left += barWidth;
                    barRect.right += barWidth;
                } // bin

                // Draw blue intensity histogram
                barRect.bottom = canvasHeight;
                barRect.left = marginWidth;
                barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
                {
                    barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mBlueHistogram[bin])/((float)blueHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                    barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlue);
                    barRect.left += barWidth;
                    barRect.right += barWidth;
                } // bin
            } // end if statement

            super.onDraw(canvas);

        } // end onDraw method

        static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            final int frameSize = width * height;

            for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                    int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                    if (y < 0) y = 0;
                    if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                        v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                        u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    }

                    int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                    int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                    int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                    int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                    if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                    if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                    if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                    rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
                }
            }
        }

        static public void decodeYUV420SPGrayscale(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height)
        {
            final int frameSize = width * height;

            for (int pix = 0; pix < frameSize; pix++)
            {
                int pixVal = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[pix])) - 16;
                if (pixVal < 0) pixVal = 0;
                if (pixVal > 255) pixVal = 255;
                rgb[pix] = 0xff000000 | (pixVal << 16) | (pixVal << 8) | pixVal;
            } // pix
        }

        static public void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram, int width, int height, int component)
        {
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                histogram[bin] = 0;
            } // bin
            if (component == 0) // red
            {
                for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
                {
                    int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
                    histogram[ pixVal ]++;
                } // pix
            }
            else if (component == 1) // green
            {
                for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
                {
                    int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
                    histogram[ pixVal ]++;
                } // pix
            }
            else // blue
            {
                for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
                {
                    int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
                    histogram[ pixVal ]++;
                } // pix
            }
        }
    } 

}
```

In the Preview, instead of previewing the image on the camera you get your bitmap:

```
 mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = getBitmap_todecode();
```

Comment: +1 for the visibility but the main problem is getting the histogram code to work with the bitmap i want. Currently it has no bitmap or any values assigned to it. If you have any idea on how to fix it then let me know please and I will award you the bounty

Comment: I edited your code and created a private Bitmap and public methods to access it. If you have any questions about it just ask! *

Comment: Hi, does it display the histograms for RGB for _tempBitmaps[0] image?? sorry I cant test it at the moment because not at home.

Comment: the private bitmap: `private Bitmap bitmap_todecode=null;`  

you can find this:  `setBitmap_todecode(_originalBitmaps[MainActivity.LEFT_IMAGE]);` in the middle of my code, is the place where you set your bitmap. when you create the view before the: `if (mBitmap != null)` you get your bitmap   like this: `mBitmap= getBitmap_todecode();`

Comment: I would have to create a hole program just to test it but i really don't have the time. You have to test it and let me know. I think that this will work. Have a nice day *

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36917/discussion-between-user1204501-and-dyna)

Comment: It didnt work but I awarded you the bounty since there were no other answers

Comment: sorry user I can't: "You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits."